# Why does Xcode 4.1 Installer ask me to quit iTunes if iTunes isn't running?

Tags: itunes, macos, xcode

Xcode 4.1 Installer downloaded from the App Store, I have no applications running except the installer and the Finder. The dialog that pops up says that iTunes needs to be quit in order for installation of Xcode to continue.

How do I make Xcode installer realize that iTunes isn't running?

Comment: The how was answered well below. The why is it changes the usb plumbing iTunes and Xcode both use to talk with iOS devices over USB. It is being over protective of your data to avoid stomping on a sync in progress and causing you or iTunes pain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a widely-reported bug in some App Store installers. It sees the `iTunesHelper` process and displays this error, even though that process is not controlled by the user.

You can open **Activity Monitor** (in /Applications/Utilities), find the process and kill it with the **Quit Process** button in the top-left corner.

[image: Activity Monitor Screenshot]

You can also instead open **Terminal** (also in /Applications/Utilities), enter the following line and press enter to kill it.

```
killall iTunesHelper
```